# Nextjs useRouter redirect and add query at the same time

Tags: next.js

Objective:
On NextJS, from any page, redirect to `/user?id=123`

We can redirect to any page with:

```js
const router = useRouter();
router.push("/user");
```

And, we can add params with:

```js
const router = useRouter();
router.query.id = '123';
router.push(router);
```

How to redirect to a page and add params to the URL?

This don't work:

```js
const router = useRouter();
router.push("/user");
router.query.id = '123';
router.push(router);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can push to a page with params by

```
router.push({
    pathname: '/user',
    query: { id: '123' },
})
```

This will go to `/user?id=123`.

In case you need to use this in the future, we can also do

```
router.push({
    pathname: '/user/[id]',
    query: { id: '123' },
})
```

This will go to `/user/123`.

Reference: [`next/router` docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router)